# What is the equivalent of the following sql statement in postgresql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have the following SQL statement that is executed in a `MySql` database and it works successfully

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*), `deleted` FROM `tweets` WHERE `id` = %s""", (tweet['id'],))
```

What is the equivalent in `postgres database`?
Trying the following

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*), deleted FROM tweets WHERE id = %s""", (tweet['id'],))
```

Fails with error

```
 ERROR: ERROR:  column "tweets.deleted" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I'm not sure where I should add the `GROUP BY` Clause.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `deleted`
FROM `tweets`
WHERE `id` = %s
```

is malformed in any database, including MySQL, because the `SELECT` columns mix an aggregation function and a non-aggregation function and there is no `GROUP BY`.

Older versions of MySQL accept this syntax (an oversight that has happily been fixed!).  The value of `deleted` comes from an *arbitrary* row.  So, you can use any value of `deleted` to match the functionality.  So, use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(deleted) as deleted
FROM `tweets`
WHERE `id` = %s
```

Comment: Yeah. The mysql db was an old one which explains why It was working. Thanks.